Ubuntu 24 can't reload session
on my Ubuntu 24.04.1, when I'm pressing ALT+F2 and running "r", I'm getting "Oh no! Something has gone wrong" error and only LogOut button
error screenshot
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 6.8.0-44-generic 
Uptime: 20 mins 
Shell: bash 5.2.21 
Resolution: 3440x1440 
DE: GNOME 46.0 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: 13th Gen Intel i5-13400F (16) @ 4.600GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Ti

cat /var/log/syslog | grep 2024-09-15T12:21 (time of the error)
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pvarenik/b4d55178d257313d2c88e352739f0a2b/raw/7a1e0a92efd6528293f43a803bdebee036ca4fa9/syslog

I get this also.
